# How to find string that completely matches total or part of input

Tags: mysql, sql

I will like to write a query to search a table containing millions of records for a value that **totally** and best matches the search string or its substring only from the beginning. Performance is of most importance.

It's like a reverse of:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name LIKE '$input%' LIMIT 1
```

As an example, I will like to search the table below for **foobar**. If **foobar** doesn't exist, search for **fooba** until the last character **f** and return the row with a total match.

```
+------------------+
|    column_name   |
+------------------+
|    foobar        |
+------------------+
|    fooba         |
+------------------+
|    foob          |
+------------------+
|    foo           |
+------------------+
|    fo            |
+------------------+
|    foobarrrrr    |
+------------------+
|    foooooooooooo |
+------------------+
|    barfoo        |
+------------------+
```

Comment: What result would you get if I searched `fred` in this table? All records starting with `f`? (just trying to understand your logic here since it's a bit out of the ordinary).

Comment: What would you return in your example?

Comment: Yes, you will get `f` as a result

Comment: Better approach is to use Full text based searching - it has lot of interesting features

Comment: I looked into fulltext matching but couldn't find most suitable method.

Comment: Not a duplicate as I don't know what the input string will be. Besides the field should be a substring or equal to the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the column value to construct a `LIKE` pattern dynamically.

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE 'foobar' LIKE CONCAT(column_name, '%')
ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that this will be slow if the table is large, as I don't think it can make use of an index. If that's a problem, building the query dynamically would better.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a really performant method, but the following might do what you want.

First, create an index on `t(column_name)`.

Then, construct the query as:

```
select t.*
from ((select t.* from table_name where column_name = $input) union all
      (select t.* from table_name where column_name = left($input, 1)) union all
      (select t.* from table_name where column_name = left($input, 2)) union all
      (select t.* from table_name where column_name = left($input, 3)) union all
      (select t.* from table_name where column_name = left($input, 4)) union all
      . . .
     ) t
order by length(t.column_name) desc
limit 1;
```

Notes:

- This is looping through the prefixes of `$input` with different lengths.  You could do this using PHP and stop at the first match.
- The index on `column_name` should be used for the comparisons.
- This is only on exact substring matches (which is how I'm interpreting the question).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping there could be a method in MySQL. I think I will use `do...while` in php and decrease the length of the string by one in PHP and search for that substring in my table. This may have bad performance for long input string.

Comment: Instead of union, you could use `WHERE column_name IN (@input, LEFT(@input, 1), LEFT(@input, 2), ...)`

Comment: @Barmar . . . My concern is whether that would always use an index on `column_name`.  MySQL can be finicky about indexes in that case.

Comment: I think MySQL is generally pretty good about using the index for `WHERE column_name IN (list)`. Where it tends to go wrong is `WHERE column_name IN (<select-query>)`

Comment: @Barmar . . . I think there is a point where it prefers to sort the list and do a binary search on the list.  The list might have to be a bit longer than a typical string would be in this case.

Comment: Theoretically it knows the proper break-even point for different strategies, and overriding it using UNION takes away that opportunity. But it's MySQL we're talking about, so it's hard to give it the benefit of the doubt.